# How do I Retrieve random value from array

Tags: php, arrays, random

print_r($rows); results in the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bg_image] => uploads/2013/06/Home_background1.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [bg_image] => uploads/2013/06/Home_background2.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [bg_image] => uploads/2013/06/Home_background3.jpg
        )

)
```

What I'm looking to get help with is randomly selecting one of the values from above. I'm fairly new to php so sorry if this is a basic question.

Comment: http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo $rows[array_rand($rows)]['bg_image'];
```

Comment: with only a couple entries speed won't matter, but here is a quick benchmark report showing `rand()` would be faster: http://www.ebrueggeman.com/blog/php_benchmarking_array_rand

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rand function to select a random index. The following will give you a random index that will be either 0, 1, or 2. Using that as the index to the array will output one of the 3 elements at random.

```
rand(0,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

use rand() function.

refer here

[PHP.net rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

Answer (score 0):

A different way from the other answers

```
$rand = mt_rand(0,2);
echo $rows[$rand]['bg_image'];
```